# Need to set a custom page as Default landing page after SSO authentication

Tags: single-sign-on, configuration, saml

I have SAML 2.0 based SSO authenitcation set in our Salesforce Org. What has to be done so that after successful authentication of the users, they should be landed on a custom page ? 
Setting up the Default Landing page under apps will only work when the user enters after giving the Org credentials.

Comment: Are you using a connected App and IDP initiated URL?

Comment: This is an SP initiated URL

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are asking for - [Using the StartURL Parameter](https://support.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_addl_params_start.htm&type=0)?

> To direct your users to a specific location after authenticating, you
>   need to specify a URL with the startURL request parameter. This URL
>   must be a relative URL; passing an absolute URL results in an error.
>   If you don’t add startURL, the user is sent to either /home/home.jsp
>   (for a portal or standard application) or to the default sites page
>   (for a site) after authentication completes.

Comment: Yes I believe so.. where do I need to set it up ?.. the article doesn't go into details..

Comment: You have to add this parameter to your Identity Provider Login URL in SSO settings

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SAML 2.0, you can also use the RelayState parameter to control where users get redirected after a successful
login.

Example:

```
https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com/idp/login?app=00000000000&RelayState=/customers/s/case/Case/00BD65400078CmqMAE
```